# How to get the user profile data in share point sandbox Visual webaprt?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

How to get the user profile data in share point sandbox Visual webapart?
I am using Spservicecontext class,But this class not available in sandbox solution so how can i get the user   Details

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access user profile in sandbox solution because SPUserProfileManager is not allowed to be used inside the sandbox solution. For a workaroundyYou can use following code to get user profile list:

```
private SPList userInformationList = null;

private SPUser user = null;

private SPListItem userItem = null;

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))

{ 
       using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) 
       { 
               // Instantiates the User Information List  
               userInformationList = SPContext.Current.Web.SiteUserInfoList;

               // Get the current user  
               user = web.EnsureUser(web.CurrentUser.Name);

               // The actual User Information is within this SPListItem  
               userItem = userInformationList.Items.GetItemById(user.ID);

              string officeLocation = userItem["Office"].ToString();

       }

}
```

You can also check :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/fc0f1fa8-0f2b-42f4-8364-d48ed344c3fd/getting-logged-in-user-details-in-sandbox-solutions-from-oob